# wordpress powered site's google search excerpt showing casino links

Tags: php, wordpress, security, google-search-console

I have wordpress blog i just checked google search result of my site they are showing excerpt containing text like below

"best site should try out for demo mode of gaming variants to adopt good gaming Participate in casino games online to take gamble online and increase your ..."

When I visit site page source shows nothing related to casino.I then used google structured data testing tool in Google Webmasters and checked Page Html it has that malicious code containing casino links .That Malicious code is attached here in following link.

http://pchat.bugs3.com/Malicious%20Code.txt

I do not know programming.Please help me get rid of this problem.

Comment: Your site has been almost certainly been compromised somehow. The standard way to fix it is to revert back to a known-good backup, and carry on from there - there's no way of knowing whether the miscreants have added extra code to your site to give themselves a backdoor, so the only way to be sure is to start from a backup. You might also want to try and figure out how they got in - are all your plugins up to date? Do any of them have security warnings? That's about as much help as I can give you, I'm afraid.